Arduino IDE doesnt find custom message although the file exists
I am trying to compile am Arduino programm but the ide just doesnt find one of my custom messages with the error No such file or directory although it exists in the folder
it is importet like this: #include <moveo_moveit/ArmJointState.h> and the message lies at Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/moveo_moveit/ArmJointState.h and looks like this:
#ifndef _ROS_moveo_moveit_ArmJointState_h
#define _ROS_moveo_moveit_ArmJointState_h

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ros/msg.h"

namespace moveo_moveit
{

  class ArmJointState : public ros::Msg
  {
    public:
      typedef int16_t _position1_type;
      _position1_type position1;
      typedef int16_t _position2_type;
      _position2_type position2;
      typedef int16_t _position3_type;
      _position3_type position3;
      typedef int16_t _position4_type;
      _position4_type position4;
      typedef int16_t _position5_type;
      _position5_type position5;
      typedef int16_t _position6_type;
      _position6_type position6;

    ArmJointState():
      position1(0),
      position2(0),
      position3(0),
      position4(0),
      position5(0),
      position6(0)
    {
    }

    virtual int serialize(unsigned char *outbuffer) const
    {
      int offset = 0;
      union {
        int16_t real;
        uint16_t base;
      } u_position1;
      u_position1.real = this->position1;
      *(outbuffer + offset + 0) = (u_position1.base >> (8 * 0)) & 0xFF;
      *(outbuffer + offset + 1) = (u_position1.base >> (8 * 1)) & 0xFF;
      offset += sizeof(this->position1);
      union {
        int16_t real;
        uint16_t base;
      } u_position2;
      u_position2.real = this->position2;
      *(outbuffer + offset + 0) = (u_position2.base >> (8 * 0)) & 0xFF;
      *(outbuffer + offset + 1) = (u_position2.base >> (8 * 1)) & 0xFF;
      offset += sizeof(this->position2);
      union {
        int16_t real;
        uint16_t base;
      } u_position3;
      u_position3.real = this->position3;
      *(outbuffer + offset + 0) = (u_position3.base >> (8 * 0)) & 0xFF;
      *(outbuffer + offset + 1) = (u_position3.base >> (8 * 1)) & 0xFF;
      offset += sizeof(this->position3);
      union {
        int16_t real;
        uint16_t base;
      } u_position4;
      u_position4.real = this->position4;
      *(outbuffer + offset + 0) = (u_position4.base >> (8 * 0)) & 0xFF;
      *(outbuffer + offset + 1) = (u_position4.base >> (8 * 1)) & 0xFF;
      offset += sizeof(this->position4);
      union {
        int16_t real;
        uint16_t base;
      } u_position5;
      u_position5.real = this->position5;
      *(outbuffer + offset + 0) = (u_position5.base >> (8 * 0)) & 0xFF;
      *(outbuffer + offset + 1) = (u_position5.base >> (8 * 1)) & 0xFF;
      offset += sizeof(this->position5);
      union {
        int16_t real;
        uint16_t base;
      } u_position6;
      u_position6.real = this->position6;
      *(outbuffer + offset + 0) = (u_position6.base >> (8 * 0)) & 0xFF;
      *(outbuffer + offset + 1) = (u_position6.base >> (8 * 1)) & 0xFF;
      offset += sizeof(this->position6);
      return offset;
    }

    virtual int deserialize(unsigned char *inbuffer)
    {
      int offset = 0;
      union {
        int16_t real;
        uint16_t base;
      } u_position1;
      u_position1.base = 0;
      u_position1.base |= ((uint16_t) (*(inbuffer + offset + 0))) << (8 * 0);
      u_position1.base |= ((uint16_t) (*(inbuffer + offset + 1))) << (8 * 1);
      this->position1 = u_position1.real;
      offset += sizeof(this->position1);
      union {
        int16_t real;
        uint16_t base;
      } u_position2;
      u_position2.base = 0;
      u_position2.base |= ((uint16_t) (*(inbuffer + offset + 0))) << (8 * 0);
      u_position2.base |= ((uint16_t) (*(inbuffer + offset + 1))) << (8 * 1);
      this->position2 = u_position2.real;
      offset += sizeof(this->position2);
      union {
        int16_t real;
        uint16_t base;
      } u_position3;
      u_position3.base = 0;
      u_position3.base |= ((uint16_t) (*(inbuffer + offset + 0))) << (8 * 0);
      u_position3.base |= ((uint16_t) (*(inbuffer + offset + 1))) << (8 * 1);
      this->position3 = u_position3.real;
      offset += sizeof(this->position3);
      union {
        int16_t real;
        uint16_t base;
      } u_position4;
      u_position4.base = 0;
      u_position4.base |= ((uint16_t) (*(inbuffer + offset + 0))) << (8 * 0);
      u_position4.base |= ((uint16_t) (*(inbuffer + offset + 1))) << (8 * 1);
      this->position4 = u_position4.real;
      offset += sizeof(this->position4);
      union {
        int16_t real;
        uint16_t base;
      } u_position5;
      u_position5.base = 0;
      u_position5.base |= ((uint16_t) (*(inbuffer + offset + 0))) << (8 * 0);
      u_position5.base |= ((uint16_t) (*(inbuffer + offset + 1))) << (8 * 1);
      this->position5 = u_position5.real;
      offset += sizeof(this->position5);
      union {
        int16_t real;
        uint16_t base;
      } u_position6;
      u_position6.base = 0;
      u_position6.base |= ((uint16_t) (*(inbuffer + offset + 0))) << (8 * 0);
      u_position6.base |= ((uint16_t) (*(inbuffer + offset + 1))) << (8 * 1);
      this->position6 = u_position6.real;
      offset += sizeof(this->position6);
     return offset;
    }

    const char * getType(){ return "moveo_moveit/ArmJointState"; };
    const char * getMD5(){ return "7bf56d1cde4c613af8c16b02c640040e"; };

  };

}
#endif


why do you call it a message file?

because its a file that describes a type of message
